# Rules used in simple differentiation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was hoping someone could explain to me how the following result is achieved, and the differentiation laws used in doing so. Thanks!

$$ \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left(-r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \right) = -\left(\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{r} \right)$$

Comment: Derivative of a product (uv )'=u'v + v'u

Answer (score 3):

It is just an application of the differenciation product rule: when taking the derivative of a product between two functions
$$ \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left(-r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \right) =\frac{1}{r}\left(-\frac{\partial r}{\partial r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}-r\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2}\right)=-\left(\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{r} \right)$$
Here you have more information:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule